# Files with bytecode are really created only for imported modules?

Tags: python, module, bytecode, cpython

In my system I have created a Python application that is composed by more than one file. The directory structure of the application is the following:

```
application_directory
  |- file_a.py
  |- file_b.py
  |- file_c.py
```

Inside the script `file_c.py` are present the following imports:

```
import file_a
from file_b import ClassB
```

When I execute the script `file_c.py` by the command line:

```
python3 file_c.py
```

in the folder `application_folder` is created a directory called `__pycache__` and inside it I find two files containing the Python bytecode and called:

```
__pycache__/file_a.cpython-310.pyc
__pycache__/file_b.cpython-310.pyc
```

**Note**: I have read [this link](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201803/is_python_interpreted_or_compiled_yes.html) and [this other link](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/introduction-python-bytecode) to get information about the concepts of compilation in Python, bytecode, and Python interpreter as virtual machine.

To understand why are created this files I have search a lot and I have found many links about this topic. The most clear could be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both/57390010#57390010) that seems perfect to understand what happens in my context.

In the answer is present the following sentence:

> Running a script is not considered an import and no .pyc will be created.

So I am asking: only for modules imported are created a file with bytecode? Why is there this difference in the management of imported modules respect to not imported scripts?

---

**EDIT**
I have found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713633/how-much-of-a-speedup-does-bytecode-compilation-give-python-code/17714409#17714409) very useful to better understand how works CPython, the concept of bytecode and the file `.pyc` saved to the hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Python files are compiled to bytecode before being executed, Python just does not write the bytecode to a file.

When a module is imported from an other file, it is compiled and then cached, to make subsequent runs faster.